# Get mylyn source code

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, mylyn

Hey i want to develop my own mylyn connector please help me out where should i start from and please tell me where i can find mylyn source code. I checked out CVS repository eclipse using **dev.eclipse.org** but i didn't find out mylyn code in that project. Please help me out I am really concent about it ......................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Answer (score 2):

The Eclipse source code was moved to `git` at http://git.eclipse.org some time ago. For details about accessing see http://www.vogella.com/articles/Eclipse4Source/article.html